# How do I combine multiple rows into one row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a query that joins 4 tables. Tables are user, user_info, email and phone.
A user can have one or more phones and emails.

Here is the sql query:

```
SELECT ur.login_id as loginId, ue.user_email_address as email, up.phone_number as phone
      FROM greydeltadb.gd_user ur 
      LEFT JOIN greydeltadb.gd_user_info uri ON uri.user_id=ur.user_id  
      INNER JOIN greydeltadb.gd_user_emails ue ON ur.user_id = ue.user_id  
      INNER JOIN greydeltadb.gd_phone up  ON ur.user_id = up.user_id  
      ORDER BY ur.login_id
```

When I execute this query i get result like this for a user with 2 emails and 2 phones:

```
loginId                  email                        phone
abc                      abc@gmail.com                123456
abc                      abc@gmail.com                798446
abc                      def@gmail.com                123456
abc                      def@gmail.com                798446
```

Then I learnt about GROUP_CONCAT() the updated query is:

```
SELECT ur.login_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ue.user_email_address) as emails,
      GROUP_CONCAT(up.phone_number) as phones
      FROM greydeltadb.gd_user ur 
      LEFT JOIN greydeltadb.gd_user_info uri ON uri.user_id=ur.user_id  
      INNER JOIN greydeltadb.gd_user_emails ue ON ur.user_id = ue.user_id  
      INNER JOIN greydeltadb.gd_phone up  ON ur.user_id = up.user_id  
      GROUP BY ur.login_id
```

this query returns the result:

```
loginId                  email                                                                    phone
abc                      abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com                123456, 798446,123456, 798446
```

But I want the output to be:

```
loginId                  email                                        phone
abc                      abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com                123456, 798446
```

Please help.

Comment: add distinct to the inside of group_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use DISTINCT clause, see the documentation of [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
> GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
>              [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
>                  [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
>              [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

> In MySQL, you can get the concatenated values of expression combinations. **To eliminate duplicate values, use the DISTINCT clause.** To sort values in the result, use the ORDER BY clause.................

---

In case of your query, use just:

```
SELECT ur.login_id, 
      GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ue.user_email_address ) as emails,
      GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT up.phone_number ) as phones
      .....
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need a `distinct`

```
    SELECT ur.login_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct ue.user_email_address) as 
    emails,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct up.phone_number) as 
     phones
     FROM greydeltadb.gd_user ur 
     LEFT JOIN greydeltadb.gd_user_info uri ON 
     uri.user_id=ur.user_id  
  INNER JOIN greydeltadb.gd_user_emails ue ON 
     ur.user_id = ue.user_id  
  INNER JOIN greydeltadb.gd_phone up  ON ur.user_id = 
  up.user_id  
  GROUP BY ur.login_id
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not using `uri`, so it is not needed in the query.

Second, you have a `left join` that is basically doing nothing.  I suspect you want users, even those with no phones or no emails.  If so:

```
SELECT ur.login_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ue.user_email_address) as emails,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT up.phone_number) as phones
FROM greydeltadb.gd_user ur LEFT JOIN
     greydeltadb.gd_user_emails ue
     ON ur.user_id = ue.user_id LEFT JOIN
     greydeltadb.gd_phone up
     ON ur.user_id = up.user_id  
GROUP BY ur.login_id  ;
```